# Join/convert points to polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon

(I am using QGIS 2.6 Brighton)

I have 2 shps, one points and another one polygons. I need to make them one.

Is there a way to join them or convert the points to polygons? Vonoroi doesnt work for me this time as the points are individual plant locations. I thought that might be possible to create regular polygons (1mx1m) instead of each point. Ore anyother size, really....

I've tried "points2one", I thought that every point could be a different little polygon... but didn't work or I didn't know how to do it (if this is possible....)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add information of what kind of polygons you would like to create from the points. It's currently not clear at all what you are looking for.

Comment: `every point could be a different little polygon` sounds that you are looking for the creation of buffers.

Comment: It is great! This is actually what I was looking for.      I can create a Buffer of my point using the Area column.      So then I can add this layer to my polygon layers. Thank you so much!!